# Change Label Node Text on RunTime. .

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

I am having `SKLabelNode` with text and developing a game that if it was right move, then label comes inside screen and shows correct and if wrong then it should show that "wrong". I am using Physics Integration and performing actions on body collision. Based on actions i want to change label node text. 
All actions are being performed on touches began method in **SpriteKit**. I created this code:

```
SKNode *myLableNode =[self childNodeWithName: labelNodeName];
```

Now i can not access text property of Sprite Label to change on runtime. Like myLabelNode.text in touches began method.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shows how a you can change text dynamically

```
@implementation MyScene
{
    SKLabelNode *_words;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    _words = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
    _words.fontSize = 30;
    _words.fontColor = [SKColor yellowColor];
    _words.position = CGPointMake(150,150);
    _words.text = @"HELLO";
    [self addChild:_words];

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:0.15 green:0.15 blue:0.3 alpha:1.0];


}
return self;
}



-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        _words.text = @"WORLD";

    }
}
```

Comment: Thats right but as i said i am changing property of label in touchesBagan method. So i will surely not be going to Add SKLabel Node, set its coolor, font name and its position each and every time the user touches the screen.

Comment: Does it answer your question ?

Comment: So i have defined label node  as '- (SKLabelNode*)message{
    SKLabelNode *messageNode = [SKLabelNode
                              labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
    messageNode.text = _messageContent;
    messageNode.fontSize = 42;
    messageNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),self.frame.size.height+10);
    messageNode.name = @"messageNode";
    
    return messageNode;
}
'

Comment: Added it as child. '[self addChild:[self message]];' Now what i want to do is change text of the label on touch. Like there is condition that if user taps wrong element then label is coming inside screen and says wrong and going back. If he taps right element then label says "Correct". Just want to change its text.

Comment: This is how i am getting label node in touchesBegan method. SKLabelNode *my = [SKLabelNode lab]
    SKNode*  messageNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"messageNode"];

Comment: just make a global Var for your label node

Comment: Already done it. Buut not working.  See  messageNode.text = _messageContent. I am changing value of _messageContent. But label is not updating it.

Comment: add a log statement - test _messageContent is changing as u expect.

Comment: I made a demo app, and it changes as expected.

Comment: I have seen your edited answer now. Looks this is the method to do it. But when i declare SKLableNode globally, how can i get it add to the scene?

Comment: I suggest you go here and do some tutorials http://www.raywenderlich.com good luck

Comment: You solved it. I have already taken and seeing each and every tutorial released by raywenderlich. anyways. Thanks for help.

Answer (score -2):

it's a label property and also u can give a unique tag also label.

```
UILabel *label = =[UILabel alloc]init];
label.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
[[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTap)]     autorelease];
[label addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

-Below are method for label touch.

```
//touches begin method
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event;

//touches end method
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
      UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
      if (CGRectContainsPoint([self.site frame], [touch locationInView:self.view])){
       //do whatever you want
     }
}
//touches move method
- (void)touchesMove:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I greatly appreciate your answer. But i have asked question in Apple gaming Framework, SpriteKit's Context. SKLabelNode is in SpriteKit.